# iOS SWIFT - File Archive - Argument Type "[String?]" : does not conform to expected type'AnyObject'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I am trying to write into an Archive and getting this error .

My tech stack is : XCode 7.1 Beta and SWIFT .Appreciate if any of you could share the exact code to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Argument Type "[String?]" : does not conform to expected type'AnyObject'

```
@IBAction func saveArch(sender: AnyObject) {

    var contactArray = [name.text, address.text, phone.text]
    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(contactArray,
        toFile: dataFilePath!)

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Array is not of type AnyObject

You should try

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(NSArray(array: contactArray),
    toFile: dataFilePath!)
```

You are sending a swift `[]` object that does not conform to `AnyObject` since arrays and object are different things in swift.

#### NSArray cannot contains optionals

You also have a problem with optionals: one or all of your `.text` is of type String? (therefor it might be nil).

If you are positive none of this field is nil, you can use

```
var contactArray = [name.text!, address.text!, phone.text!]
```

Or change the declaration.

If you are not sure, you should do something like

```
var contactArray = [String]()

for element in [name.text, address.text, phone.text] where element != nil {
    array.append(element!)
}
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(NSArray(array: contactArray),
    toFile: dataFilePath!)
```

This way you only add non `nil` elements to the contactArray
By the way, Xcode 7.1 is out. No need to use the beta anymore

Comment: Thanks , I made the above change and it gives a different error now : " Cannot invoke initializer for type "NSArray" with an argument list of type '(array: [String?])'

Comment: @ArchesArches I made an edit; you had actually two distinct typing issues

Comment: Excellent - thanks a lot , the above code fixed it all.

Comment: @ArchesArches Great ! if it did, please accept the answer :)